# How can I bypass Android Chrome's Account Manager for OAuth?

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-oauth

I recently migrated my application to authenticate with Google via a [Chrome Custom Tab](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs) instead of an internal WebView using a non-system account. Everything works well unless the user is syncing/logged into any Google/Gmail account on the Google Chrome application.

When the user is signed into Google Chrome on their phone, the ServiceLogin url routes to Google Chrome's system account management interface:

Screenshot of Chrome account management:
[image]

Is there a way to have Chrome continue to route to the authentication screen? I looked at Google's documentation for webserver OAuth2 implementation and did not find a query parameter that would route to an in-browser experience.

Edit: This appears to happen on Android 7.1.1, but not 7.0.0.

Edit 2:

The flow is:

1. User is in my app
2. I send a Chrome Custom Tab intent (or `ACTION_VIEW` intent) with a given URI.
3. That URI *should* redirect to a pre-filled Google log in page, or if the user is logged in with that account in the browser it should be a permission approval page.
4. Instead, on Android 7.1.1 with Chrome installed, Chrome redirects me to a native account management screen (image below). This only happens if I am logged into Chrome with any Gmail/Google Apps account on this device.

I do not want my user redirected to this account management Activity/screen. This essentially forces the user to add an account that their authenticating with to be a system account, and that does not seem to be a reasonable requirement for Google to set forth. I am looking for a way to avoid Chrome gobbling up account webpage links and redirecting users to this native account management screen.

Comment: Do you mean post auth - sending to the resulting page? I have not done this in android but have done a bit of work in chrome with oauth2. The bounce page is specified in the authorized redirect uri's in the google oauth client admin panel. That is the target when auth is completed and your server page will get the state/code query parms to use for constructing an access tokens when the browser lands on your target page to complete the auth cycle. Then you can direct the page anywhere you want. URL: https://console.developers.google.com/apis

Comment: Sorry, my post may be a bit unclear.

This is after the user hits my initial redirect link and prior to the user entering credentials or approving permissions. 

Adding the flow to the post above.

Comment: Maybe too late now but if still needed - how are you building up your authorization URI that you are sending the google oauth2/auth service? Keeping in mind, I only work with OAuth2 from java/chrome on a workstation and stretching to help with it from Android.

Comment: @KevinCarpenter, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @grebulon – As best as I can tell, this is working as designed by Google. They want people to auth accounts on the device, and this is a way of encouraging that behavior.